# Share data, received from notifications when the app is in the background to main app

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, background

When the App in background I handling notification data in the `_handler`.

`FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handler);`

It's working good.

On notification click the App start and need to get the notification data.

How do I inform the App?

I'm trying with `shared_preferences` but its working with delay

Answer (score 0):

I know the reply is a bit late, but maybe it's helpful for someone else.

For me it works using the handler. It's described in the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive

Check the chapter "Handling interaction".

Using that example I can pass notification data in the app, as soon as it is started via a received notification.